# Custom Scroll View getting scrolled under Sliver Persistent Header

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, nestedscrollview, customscrollview

```
DefaultTabController(
          length: _subCategory.tabLength,
          initialIndex: 0,
          child:
NestedScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      headerSliverBuilder: (headerCtx, innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            backgroundColor: _productColor.backgroundColor,
            pinned: true,
            elevation: 0,
            forceElevated: innnerBoxIsScrolled,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("${_subCategory.currentSubCategoryName()}"),
              background: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 4,
                  bottom: 50.0,
                ),
                child: Hero(
                  tag: _subCategory.currentSubCategoryId(),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'asset/images/grocery.jpeg',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(headerCtx),
            sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: _ProductTabSliver(
                TabBar(
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black87,
                  tabs: [
                    ..._subCategory.currentTab().map(
                      (tabValue) {
                        return Tab(text: "${tabValue.fullName}");
                      },
                    ).toList()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body:CustomScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverOverlapInjector(
          handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (ctx, pdIndex) {
              final heightVisible =
                  _subCategory.advanceCompanyProductCount(pdIndex);
           
           return ProductLayout();
 },
            childCount: _subCategory.differentProductCount(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );,
    ));
```

CustomScrollList getting scrolled under sliverPersistentHeader Tab.
DefaultTabController

- NestedScrollView

  - SliverAppBar
  - SliverPersistentHeader
    -body: CustomScrollView
    - slivers: SliverChildBuilderDelegate

SliverPersistentHeader had all the tabs displayed on the top(TabBar)

Body of Nested ScrollView is CustomScrollView which has SliverChildBuilderDelegate has a child.

On scrolling the list, my list scroll behind the tabs of sliver persistent header. Seems like sliverPersistentHeader is transparent and list scrolls can be seen behind.

To solve this problem, I had tried SliverOverlapInjector and SliverOverlapAbsorber, but that didn't help.

CustomScrollView scroll problem image is 4th for better understanding. Sunflower oil card on scrolling reaches behind the tab bar.

Images:

[Sliver Overlap Absorber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmHyI.jpg)

[Sliver Overlap Injector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATsXz.jpg)

[Custom Scroll View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Y2r.jpg)

[Overlapping Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJUws.png)

Comment: and why rhose `SliverOverlapInjector` / `SliverOverlapAbsorber`? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: My List is getting scroll over the tabs and I want to remove this effect . I had share image related to this image no 4. Sunflower oil on scrolling reach below the tabs.

Comment: why cannot you just use `CustomScrollView`?

Comment: I had tried but then also this overlapping problem remains

Comment: I had used SliverOverlapInjector/ SliverOverlapAbsorber to remove this overlapping effect but not working

Comment: I had read this article https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21551

Answer (score 3):

```
class ProductAppBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  
    return NestedScrollView(
      physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
      headerSliverBuilder: (headerCtx, innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
        return <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 200.0,
            backgroundColor: _productColor.backgroundColor,
            pinned: true,
            elevation: 0,
            forceElevated: innnerBoxIsScrolled,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("${_subCategory.currentSubCategoryName()}"),
              background: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 4,
                  bottom: 50.0,
                ),
                child: Hero(
                  tag: _subCategory.currentSubCategoryId(),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'asset/images/grocery.jpeg',
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(headerCtx),
            sliver: SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: _ProductTabSliver(
                TabBar(
                  onTap: (index) {
                    _subCategory.updateTabIndex(index);
                  },
                  labelColor: Colors.white,
                  unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black87,
                  tabs: [
                    ..._subCategory.currentTab().map(
                      (tabValue) {
                        return Tab(text: "${tabValue.fullName}");
                      },
                    ).toList()
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: TabBarView(
        children: _subCategory.currentTab().map((tabElement) {
          return ProductScreenLayout();
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ProductTabSliver extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final TabBar _tabBar;

  _ProductTabSliver(this._tabBar);

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    final _productColor =
        Provider.of<ColorConfig>(context, listen: false).randomProductColor();

    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: _productColor.backgroundColor,
        ),
        child: _tabBar);
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Instead of returning just TabBar Widget from the SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate wrapping it with Container and setting backgroundColor solve my problem.

Inside class _ProductTabSliver build method I had wrapped the Container

Comment: Wow! It works! Thank you!

I have NestedScrollView and inside it CustomScrollView. My headerSliverBuilder was not scrolled until I wrapped CustomScrollView in Container

Thank u!